# Cannot disable Hyper-v and Windows Hypervisor Platform together

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I have followed these instructions on my Windows 10 PC:

1) Go to Control Panel/Programs and Features/Turn Windows Features on and Off

2) 'Hyperv' and 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' are enabled.  Therefore I disable them by unticking the two checkboxes.

3) Click ok.

4) At this point I expect to see a message saying success (please restart your PC).  Instead I see this:

[image]

After I click close and then restart my PC.  After this I notice the two settings are still enabled.  What is the problem?

[image]

I have Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform installed as shown below:

[image]

I can disable one or the other but not both.  If I attempt to disable both (either at the same time or one after the other (restarting in between) then I see the error in point four above).

Here is what I see when I am troubleshooting:

[image]

Comment: Why do you even want to disable them and which one?

Comment: @Seth, I have a problem with Docker and the advice is to restart them both together.  Restarting them individually does not help.

Comment: If you want to restart why not just do that? Where are you seeing an error if you disable both?

Comment: @Seth, what do you mean by "restart"? If you mean restart the PC, then I can confirm that I do this.

Comment: @Seth, I see the error at either of these points: 1) When both features are disabled together - the result is that none are disabled or 2) When one feature is disabled after the other i.e. the point the second feature is disabled.  Does that make sense?

Comment: No it's still unclear where you're seeing that error. When trying to run Docker afterwards? When clicking OK on the change dialog? After Windows tries to apply the changes? After a reboot? What is the actual Docker problem you're trying to solve and where did you read the advice that suggests so "restart". If you just need to restart those features that's done after rebooting your machine. So you wouldn't need to disable/enable any of them. Does the error message contain any more information? What about your Event log?

Comment: The [Windows Hypervisor Platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/api/) allows for 3rd party, non-Hyper-V VM services to use the Windows Hypervisor (VMware, VirtualBox, etc.).  Have you tried removing that first, rebooting, then removing Hyper-V, rebooting, and finally re-selecting both to reinstall?  If so, a repair install should be a last resort, first turning to `DISM` and `SFC`.  First, run `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup`, then `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`, Reboot, then `SFC /ScanNow`, Reboot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have re-written the question in an attempt to spell out my problem more clearly.

Comment: An interesting log to look at is: "C:\windows\logs\cbs\CBS.log" check if you can find interesting errors in this file.

Comment: Several users have requested you provide information.  You have yet to include information, that provides that information, in the question body. I will be able to better clarify my answer if I knew which version of Windows 10 you were using.  It would also help if you provided a screnshot indicating if Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform was installed.  The cause of 0x80073701 is directly linked to WinSxS corruption, which is the reason running the command to repair it, is critical to understanding and fixing your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have edited the OP with an update containing two screenshots.  Thanks.

Comment: I decided to crop your large images, remove your personal email in the process which was contained in your second image, make some other small adjustments.  It still remains unclear if `SFC /scannow` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` detected any problems or not.  However, you are running a 1803 build from over a month ago, which is an indication your system has not sucessfully installed an update in over a month.  It might also be on purpose though but a good quality answer requires understanding which case it is.

Comment: @Ramhound , I have added another screenshot.  Thanks.

Comment: Your issue is due to your WinSXS directory.  The DISM command you ran should have worked.  There a reason you have not installed any updates in a month?

Comment: @Ramhound, there is no reason I have not installed the updates - I thought they were installed automatically.  Do you think this is what the problem could be? I will install them later when I return to the PC.

Comment: Manually installing updates appears to of resolved the issue.  Thanks.  If you would like to post an answer then I will accept it so other users know what to do.