# Cannot enable Intel VT-d in the BIOS

Tags: bios, virtualization, android

My CPU is: Intel (R) Core i7 950 @ 3.07 GHz. I have the following BIOS: P6X58D-E version 0502.

I have successfully enabled Virtualisation by following these instructions:

1) Enter BIOS

2) Go to Advanced /CPU Configuration /Intel Virtualisation(R) Tech

I then reboot and eveything is ok except I have this problem: [Cannot disable Hyper-v and Windows Hypervisor Platform together](https://superuser.com/questions/1473192/cannot-disable-hyper-v-and-windows-hypervisor-platform-together) i.e. hardware acceleration is not working when I try to debug Xamarin apps using x86 architectures.

Therefore I did some more research and found another setting in the BIOS:

Advanced/Chipset/Intel VT-d Configuration/Intel VT-d

However, when I enable this; I cannot boot Windows i.e. it hangs as shown below:

[image]

It was like this for one hour. I then switched the PC off; entered the BIOS and disabled Intel VT-d. Then the PC restarted as normal.

Please note that I enabled this setting with Hyper-v enabled and disabled and it made no difference i.e. I witnessed the same behaviour. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then reboot and eveything is ok except I have this problem: Cannot disable Hyper-v and Windows Hypervisor Platform together i.e. hardware acceleration is not working when I try to debug Xamarin apps using x86 architectures.

Hyper-V nor Windows Hypervisor Platform actually require VT-d they only require VT-x.  Infact it is not possible for you to enable VT-d, since you have a [Core i7 950](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37150/intel-core-i7-950-processor-8m-cache-3-06-ghz-4-80-gt-s-intel-qpi.html), which does not support it.  So while you might have enabled it within your firmware, your processor does not actually support it, which is the reason Windows could not boot.  **I suspect you might have a motherboard which supported a processor that does support VT-d.**

> hardware acceleration is not working when I try to debug Xamarin apps using x86 architectures.
> What am I doing wrong?

Xamarin is designed for Android and iOS development, which suggests you are attempting to use HAXM, which itself requires virtilization technology to be enabled (VT-x) and Hyper-V to be installed.

The error in your other question suggests, the edition of Windows 10 you have, specifically the `Windows Side By Side` (WinSxS) directory might be simply corrupt and/or never included Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform.

> Does my processor support x86 hardware acceleration?
>
> If you could point me to the line in the specification that says whether hardware acceleration is supported then I would be very grateful.

Yes

[image]

Comment: But I can run Docker with no problems whatsoever.  Surely this proves that Windows is not corrupt?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.  +1 for: "VT-d is not supported by your processor".  Does my processor support x86 hardware acceleration?

Comment: If you could point me to the line in the specification that says whether hardware acceleration is supported then I would be very grateful and close this question.  I cannot see any reference to hardware acceleration.  I guess I am a software developer struggling a bit on the hardware side of things.

Comment: Thanks I agree that your answer does answer the specofic question.  The two questions I have asked today are linked.  Therefore one more thing......  if I grab a windows 10 iso and perform a repair upgrade then do you think it will resolve both issues? I.e. enable me to debug xamarin using an x86 emulator and enable me to uninstall hyperv and windows hypervisor platform together? Thanks again.