# Bluestacks Hyper-V not disabling

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, hypervisor, bluestacks, windows-10-pro

i recently tried to install Bluestacks on windows 10 pro (x64) and upon installation i am greeted by the "Bluestacks is unable to use hardware assisted virtualisation when hyper-v is enabled". Even though i have disabled "windows sandbox", "Windows hyper visor platform", "Virtual machine platform" and "Hyper-V", i also have Intel virtualisation technology enabled in the bios. i have also checked to make sure that core isolation is off in my device security settings but i keep on getting the same error. any ideas?

EDIT: my cpu is the i7-4790

Comment: I have gone to great efforts to outline specific instructions to determine if VT-x/AMD-V is enabled or disabled [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1474059/does-my-cpu-motherboard-support-vt-x/1474286#1474286). If you have an Intel process, please update your question, with the relevant information from the suggested tool.  **The only reason you would be getting this error is if another application was using the virtualization capabilities of your processor.** In other words, there is no other explaination that is possible, there is some application installed that conflicts with BlueStacks.

Answer (score 2):

After making sure the CPU Virtualization is enabled, best to uninstall Hyper V by

1. Start > search and click Turn Windows features on or off,
2. Uncheck Hyper V main node and click ok (will uninstall the hyper V feature)
3. Restart PC
4. cmd > systeminfo

   - if it says something like 'a hypervisor has been detected', bluestacks will still get the issue so run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off' to disable hyper V completely

- else, congrats bluestacks has no hyper V issues anymore

Took me like 2 hours of installing, uninstalling, reinstalling and googling trying to find out whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me, in the order I tried. The last step I figured out on my own:

1. Uninstall other hypervisors like VirtualBox
2. Remove the following Windows features:

   - Hyper-V
   - Virtual Machine Platform
   - Windows Hypervisor Platform
   - (maybe) Windows Sandbox
   - (maybe) Windows Subsystem For Linux
3. Disable Windows Security> Device Security> Core Isolation:
   Memory Integrity
4. (Possibly unrelated to your scenario) Uninstalled Bluestacks 5 with [this tool](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360057724751)
5. (What finally worked) Disable Microsoft Defender Device & Credential Guard and all other virtualization-based security features:
   There are a number of sketchy tutorials but I used [this script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/dg-readiness-tool)

   ...with these parameters:
   DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 -Disable -AutoReboot

*Note, you are disabling security features and all that implies.*