# Enable 64 bit VMs on Virtual box after recent Win10 home update

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, 64-bit, windows-update, hyper-v

I recently tried to boot up an old virtual machine in VirtualBox running Ubuntu 16.04, but was not able to run it. I tried making a fresh VM and realised that virtualbox was no longer offering 64 bit machines, which is what my disk image is.

I have tried the following:

Check that Intel Virtualization technology is enabled in bios

Check that Hyper-V isn't interfering with it according to [this guide](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/11/virtualbox-showing-32-bit-guest-versions-64-bit-host-os/#.XbLmQ9VS-Hs)

As I couldn't find Hyper-V listed I tried [this workaround](https://www.petri.com/workaround-finding-missing-hyper-v-tools-windows-10), but failed to find an update that my system would install. Some more research led me to realize that Hyper-V [is not available](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/hyper-v-is-missing/191e7c79-2c95-4417-b877-f40f6f856108) on Win10 home. As such Hyper-V shouldn't be the problem?

From here on I'm kind of stumped. Vbox used to work on this very machine maybe a year back, but at some point since then something seems to have broken it. I have do not have any other virtualization software installed which, together with some hints I found while googling, leads me to believe that the problem is with some Windows update.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There are other features that can also disable virtualization techniques: Windows Sandbox, Windows Defender "Core Isolation" respectively “Memory Integrity".

Comment: Edit your question to specify the specific update you installed

Comment: Windows Sandbox can only be enabled on Windows 10 Professional.  This [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1474059/does-my-cpu-motherboard-support-vt-x/1474286#1474286) suggests the use of an Intel tool that will determine if VT-x is available or not.  Provide an update to your question with the relevant information

Comment: Certain antivirus programs will also block hardware virtualization, Avast and Kaspersky will block by default.