# Task manager shows Virtualization as off but BIOS shows it as on

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I am running into an issue with WSL not working as of recent.

When trying to launch WSL I get an error:
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QCxD.png)

```
$ wsl
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2-install
```

- [Screenshot of system information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmLCx.png)
- [Screenshot of intel processor identification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq56I.png)
- [Screenshot of Task manager showing virtualization disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Mxt.png)
- [Screenshot of Windows Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKcSk.png)

For BIOS I have confirmed Virtualization is on. At this point I am at a loss, I have tried a few different things that I found online and nothing seems to be working.

---

Update 1:

[BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaPy0.jpg)

[Windows Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXbII.png)

Comment: You need to enable the Windows Hypervisor Platform.  Please install it then update your screenshots

Comment: Additionally, every single one of your screenshots, indicates that hardware virtualization is disabled.  Where is the screenshot of your UEFI configuration?

Comment: @Ramhound - Thank you for the quick response, I updated the post with some screenshots of my bios, and with the Hypervisor Platform turned on. I have since restarted and getting the same error.

Comment: I have heard of a bug where the enabled status of VT- x was flipped. Additionally, Hyper-V isn’t required for WSL2, so I would uninstall it, and see if the [Intel utility](https://superuser.com/questions/1474059/does-my-cpu-motherboard-support-vt-x/1474286#1474286) gives different results

Comment: @Ramhound - Just tried that same thing in the Intel Utility and when launching WSL. CPU does show VT-x https://i.imgur.com/ax9fXHP.png

Comment: CPU-Z doesn’t show if hardware virtualization is enabled or disabled just if the CPU supports it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by updating my bios and that fixed it.