# How Is it possible to use virtualization engine options in vmware workstation when using Hypervisor?

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation, hypervisor

I use the vmware workstations virtualization engine heavily, but I noticed after enabling WSL2 which requires the Hypervisor to be enabled, I can no more run any virtualization with those options activated.

Here is the screenshot from one of my old vms (I believe 1.15) showing the virtualization engine options. (side note: I guess the 1.16 has more options here as well.)
[image]

Is it possible to still use these options even when Hypervisor is enabled and running in windows 10? if not, what other choices do I have to get the performance I used to get before enabling hypervisor and loosing these options?

Comment: What version of VMWare exactly?  What version of Windows are you running?  Do you have Hyper-V enabled?  If so why do you have it enabled? Hyper-V is to required for WSL2.

Comment: I believe I have mentioned all of t hose informations. here it goes again, As I said its 15.1 workstation. this is also the case for any future version as far as I know including 16.1 pro. yes I also pointed that out that Hypervisor is enabled becasue of wsl2 and when thats enabled I can not use these options in vmware. windows 10 (build 19042) and onward, also any version of windows 10 should suffice to show the issue as far as I'm aware

Comment: Your question does not specify which version of VMWare you are using nor does it indicate what version of Windows 10 you are using.  If you mean "1.15" I have no idea what that is in reference to.  I will again point out, that Hyper-V is not required, to use WSL2 only Virtual Machine Platform.  It shouldn't matter since the current version of VMWare is compatible with Hyper-V provided you are running Windows 10 21H2.  19042 is Windows 10 20H2. You should also try upgrading to VMWare Workstation Pro 16.2.3

Comment: @Ramhound thanks a lot. really appreciate it. for 15.1 I meant, vmware workstation 15.1 (now that I recheck, its 15.5.1). For the wsl2 and hypervisor, I have a windows 10 machine (21H2) at work and vmware Workstation Pro 16.1.2 and noticed I could only install wsl2 after running executing sth like `BCDEDIT /Set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype auto` and only after that it started working and then vmware virtualization engine options wouldnt work. please allow me to retest this using what you kindly explained here and report back.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, I unchecked all hypervisor realted options in "Turn Windows Features On" section and only checked the Virtual Machine Platform. as I already pointed out this just wont work and caused my wls2 to error out : "Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.            For information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2-install                                                                Press any key to continue...  ". 
also if I re-enable hypervisor it will all start working again so the BIOS etc are all corretly set

Comment: OK, I had to disable the BCEDIT change I had made and that worked just fine as you mentioned. but the vmware workstation 16.1.2 pro (that I have) wont execute with virtualization engine options enabled in this mode either. so I'm back at the beginning!

Comment: Hardware virtualization (VT-x) has to be enabled but Hyper-V does NOT have to be enabled. If you are still getting this error, go through ALL applications, and determine any application that might be using VT-x and verify VT-x is actually still enabled.

Comment: VT-x Is enabled though I have no idea how I can check which application uses VT-x I believe only Vmware and or hypervisor utilize this. I'm not aware of any other apps on my system that uses that feature so I'm clueless here

Comment: Docker, Avast, Android Emulators, Intel HAXM are a few suggestions. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1474059/does-my-cpu-motherboard-support-vt-x/1474286#1474286) is how you can check the status of VT-x

Comment: There is no thirdparty application in the background that uses VT-x. Task manager shows VT-x is enabled and active, so I guess there is no way to have these two work together:(