# Why is system acceleration disabled according to VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, bios, virtualization

I have downloaded a prebuilt Ubuntu virtual machine and I am trying to run it using Virtualbox 6.1.    I see this when opening the settings of the virtual machine and the virtual machine will not start.

[image]

I have tried selecting the Acceleration tab in System settings and unticking: "Hardware Virtualisation", but the message does not disappear and I cannot click ok (because it is greyed out - I assume the button can be clicked once the issues are resolved); only cancel.

I believe my Motherboard (P6X58D-E version 0502) and CPU (Core I7 950) supports acceleration as described here: [Cannot enable Intel VT-d in the BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/1473361/cannot-enable-intel-vt-d-in-the-bios).  Virtualisation is enabled according to task manager:

[image]

Here are my CPU BIOS settings:

[image]

Intel VT-d Configuration/Intel VT-d is disabled in the BIOS because of the issue described in the thread I have linked to.  However, the answerer says it does not need to be enabled for acceleration.

What else can I do?

Update

1. I have the Docker v19.03.13 installed, however it is not running
2. I have tried VirtualBox versions 6.0.24-139119 and VirtualBox-6.1.18-142142.
3. I have AVG installed
4. I have the following windows features.  I have tried disabling hyperv, however I want to use VirtualBox with hyperv ideally (is there a way to find out what is using vt-x?):

[image]

Comment: It could well be in use by Hyper-V, WSL2, Windows Defender, or any other number of things. VMWare and VirtualBox should have options to use the Windows Virtual Machine Platform methods which should then share the option better.

Comment: [VirtualBox 6.1+ requires VT-x to run 32-bit guest VMs](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog) this change was made in 2019.  What security software do you have installed that might be using VT-x?  What version of VirtualBox are you using exactly (full version number)?  What optional Windows features do you have installed?  What other software like (I.e Docker) do you have installed.  You might have enabled VT-x but something other than VirtualBox is using it.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have added an update.

Comment: Docker being installed is the source of your problem.  What security features do you have enabled within AVG?  What AVG product precisely are you running?

Comment: @Ramhound, I have tried uninstalling Docker already.

Comment: @w0051977 - Your question nor your comment made any mention of that.

Comment: Without some very specific information about the configuration of AVG this question really cannot be answered.  I decided to just vote to close it.

Comment: @Ramhound, just reinstalled windows 10 and then installed virtualbox (in that order I e. No av etc).  I still have the same problem.

Comment: I will have to conclude that despite the Intel documentation saying VT-x is support, it actually is not supported, given that it does not work.  Since VirtualBox 6.1+ now requires VT-x in order to run any virtual machine, VirtualBox, cannot be used on your hardware.

Comment: I suggest you submit this problem to the VirtualBox forum and provide the log VirtualBox generates.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox may have difficulties co-existing with Hyper-V.

Try to disable the Windows features of "Hyper-V" and "Virtual Machine Platform".
I notice that you have installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), and
without these features you will be limited to WSL version 1 which is slightly
less performant if you're a heavy user of it.

If it doesn't help, you could perhaps try VMware instead of Virtualbox,
to see if it has better hardware support for your computer
(leaving the above Windows features disabled for the moment).